# Boost::typeof compiler problem: mangling typeof, use decltype instead

Tags: c++, templates, boost, typeof

short example:

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/core.hpp>
using namespace boost;


template<class T, class U>
BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL(T() + U()) add2(const T& t, const U& u)
{
    return t + u;
};

int main(){

     typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(add2(2.5, 1.5)) type; // get type -> works

     BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((is_same<type, double>::value)); // check if double -> no error -> double

     double xxx = add2(1.5,1.5); // cause the problems
        return 0;
 }
```

When i try to compile this i become a error like:

g++-4.3: sorry, unimplemented: mangling typeof, use decltype instead

g++-4.2: `internal compiler error: in write_type, at cp/mangle.c:1648
     Please submit a full bug report,
     with preprocessed source if appropriate.
     See <URL:http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
     For Debian GNU/Linux specific bug reporting instructions,
     see <URL:file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2/README.Bugs>.`

gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)
gcc version 4.2.4 (Debian 4.2.4-6)

Where is the Problem or what i do wrong?a

Comment: Perhaps if your compiler supports it, use the C++0x features: `auto add2(const T& t, const U& u) -> decltype(t + u)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The example in the typeof documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.typo) first wraps the result of the BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL macro in a templated struct, then uses that when declaring the function. Does that work any better for you?

```
template<class T, class U>
struct result_of_add2
{
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF_TPL(T() + U()) type;
};

template<class T, class U>
typename result_of_add2<T, U>::type add2(const T& t, const U& u)
{
    return t + u;
};
```